# The type or namespace name 'TableAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs'

Tags: azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I followed example on https://github.com/czar3985/AzureFunctionsAndTableStorage but I keep getting compile error. Compiling against .net 6.0

.cs

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
//using Azure.Data.Tables;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage;
```

.csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.Tables" Version="12.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.23.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table" Version="1.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: You are mixing legacy version of azure packages with the newer version, I would be surprised if it work. Check here for differences between them, 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/MigrationGuide.md
maybe starting a new clean project will be the fast way to get all the package reference for the new version.

Answer (score 0):

- **TableAttribute** requires the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namespace.
- By default, it got included while creating the .Net 6 Azure Function.
- [`TableAttribute`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/Schema/TableAttribute.cs) belongs to the *System.ComponentModel.Annotations* assembly, which [is not part](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/src/netstandard/ref) of the .NET Standard.
- If you didn't find the above namespace in the project, You need to install it as a package:

```cs
Install-Package System.ComponentModel.Annotations -Version 4.6.0
```

and include it in the using namespace as shown below:

[image]